# Execute Linux shell command using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, linux, shell

I have a HTML page and that have two buttons, i need to run 2 different **"sh"** commands when i click on the buttons, using PHP and Ajax how can i achieve this?

Comment: what did you achieve so far?

Comment: by writing code..

Answer (score 1):

You can [ajax request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to php page and use **[exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)**

```
<?php
    // outputs the username that owns the running php/httpd process
    // (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)
    echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Comment: if he have permission to do that!

Comment: Of course, It is the basic to execute Shell command using php 

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php